# take space after comma in math mode

Tags: math-mode, spacing, punctuation

I have searched hard for the answer to this question but have not been able to find it. I'm typing an article and I have to write a lot of formulas, and for me it's more beautiful write
`f(x, y)` than `f(x,y)`. I'm tired of always writing a thin space `\,` after a comma in mathmode, and it's also confusing. Is there a way to automate this?

Comment: Welcome. // You can define useful macros via \newcommand and, for example, incorporate Davids suggestion there. View it as your individual shorthand notation. // See e.g. here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Macros#New_commands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're willing to have more space after *every* comma in math mode.

```
\documentclass{article}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \mathchardef\stdcomma=\mathcode`,
  \mathcode`,="8000
}
\begingroup\lccode`~=`, \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\stdcomma\,}

\begin{document}

$f(x,y)$

$a,b,c$

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you only want the space when specifying variables, you can use the same method as the package `icomma`, but this requires discipline in input: if a comma is followed by a space (in math mode), a thin space is added.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \mathchardef\stdcomma=\mathcode`,
  \mathcode`,="8000
}
\begingroup\lccode`~=`, \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{%
  \futurelet\@let@token\spaced@comma
}
\newcommand{\spaced@comma}{%
  \stdcomma
  \ifx\@let@token\@sptoken\,\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$f(x, y)$ % added space

$f(x,y)$ % compare with the standard

$a,b,c$ % no space is added

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd avoid setting `\thinmuskip` to a larger value. Here's why.

```
\documentclass{article}

\thinmuskip=6mu

\begin{document}

$f(x,y)=\sin x-\sin y$ % with the new setting

\thinmuskip=3mu

$f(x,y)=\sin x-\sin y$ % with the standard setting

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, `\thinmuskip` is not only used after commas, but in several other places, which would be affected by the same enlarged space.

Comment: Indeed, I didn't pay attention immediately, thanks. I have tried your method and it works great. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

`,` is `\mathpunct` so has  a thin space by default unless you have changed the settings. Compare with `{,}`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$f(x, y)$

$f(x{,} y)$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but people want from me a little bit big space    \documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}

\begin{document}

$f(x,\, y)$%like this
$f(x, y)$
$f(x,y)$
$f(x{,}y)$
\end{document}

Comment: @FatimaBogatyreva you can increase all thin spaces, `\thinmuskip=5mu` (but  would not)

Comment: It works, thanks a lot. I rummaged through the entire Internet and did not find it and suffered from multiple typing \, in all my formulas.

Comment: @FatimaBogatyreva are you_sure_you want that? You should change `\medmuskip` and `\thickmuskip` to be larger than `\thinmuskip` if you do. I would advise against it.

Answer (score 2):

You may also define your own command with the space you want:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\fxy}{$f(x,\,y)$}

\begin{document}
    \fxy, compared to
    

    $f(x,y)$
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But i need it in many place, i can't put it all with newcommand. I'm searching for method for redefining comma like comma+\,

Comment: What do you mean? When you want to type f(x,  y) you type \fxy and you get it with the space you defined in \newcommand. No need for \newcommand than just once.